# Parse JSON object recursively - Java

Tags: java, json, performance, parsing, recursion

I have a JSON with list of Objects and any of the item in the list can have null or the same object as a value for a key. I am looking for a faster way to parse the json to arrive at my final result. 
The data structure looks like -

```
[
    {
        "firstName": "Bruce",
        "familyMembers": null
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Gates Family",
        "familyMembers": [
            {
                "firstName": "Bill",
                "familyMembers": null
            },
            {
                "firstName": "Steve",
                "familyMembers": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lee",
        "familyMembers": null
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Chan",
        "familyMembers": null
    }
]
```

The output should be a set = ("Bruce", "Bill", "Steve", "Lee", "Chan").

I am looking for a best possible way to do this in Java, such that i dont increase my response time by getting caught in this parsing hell. 
Appreciate your time on this.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: use jackson's stream parser.

Comment: On a side note. The file that you have up there does not comply to the JSON standard because the content should begin with the { } clause. E.g. { member: [ {1:2}, {3:4} ] }

Comment: Also, should the string "GatesFamily" be included into the set? Because that is reflected as the "firstName" attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try my recursive implementation.

```
public static void jsonArrayToSet(JSONArray jAry, Set<String> result, String targetKey, String subArrayKey, boolean includeNode){
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < jAry.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jObj = jAry.getJSONObject(i);
            boolean hasSubArray = false;
            JSONArray subArray = null;
            if(jObj.has(subArrayKey)){
                Object possibleSubArray = jObj.get(subArrayKey);
                if(possibleSubArray instanceof JSONArray){
                    hasSubArray = true;
                    subArray = (JSONArray) possibleSubArray;
                }
            }
            if(hasSubArray){
                if(includeNode){
                    result.add(jObj.getString(targetKey));
                }
                jsonArrayToSet(subArray, result, targetKey, subArrayKey, includeNode);
            } else {
                result.add(jObj.getString(targetKey));
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`jAry`: The source `JSONArray`.

`result`: The `Set` you want to write in.

`targetKey`: The key that maps to an entry which you want to add to `result`.

`subArrayKey`: The key that map to a sub-`JSONArray`.

`includeNode`: When current `JSONOnject` is a node containing sub-array, add it to `result` or not.

In your case, you can call:

```
jsonArrayToSet(yourJsonArray, yourSet, "firstName", "familyMembers", false);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my comment.

Your first issue would be the content in your JSON file. Based on the standard, it should be wrapped around with a set of { }.

Example

```
{ 
    "members": [
        {
            "firstName": "Bruce",
            "familyMembers": null
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Gates Family",
            "familyMembers": [
                {
                    "firstName": "Bill",
                    "familyMembers": null
                },
                {
                    "firstName": "Steve",
                    "familyMembers": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Lee",
            "familyMembers": null
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Chan",
            "familyMembers": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Also, I think the value "Gates Family" should be part of the output? Since it is under the "FirstName" attribute.

Anyway, here is my solution that is based on the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library. It also uses Goggle's [GSon](https://github.com/google/gson) library where I use it for reading the JSON file.

```
import org.json.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
import com.google.common.io.Files;

public class solution {

    public static final String JSON_DATA_FILE_PATH = "./data/source_37848106.json";

    private static boolean hasMoreFamilyName(JSONObject json) {
        return json.has("familyMembers") && json.get("familyMembers") != JSONObject.NULL;
    }

    private static void trackFirstName(Map<String, Integer> nameTracker, JSONObject json) {
        if (!nameTracker.containsKey(json.getString("firstName"))) {
            nameTracker.put(json.getString("firstName"), /*DUMMY VALUE =*/1);
        }
    }

    private static void getNames(Map<String,Integer> nameTracker, JSONArray jsonArr) {
        for (int i = 0; i< jsonArr.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject item = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i);
            if (hasMoreFamilyName(item)) {
                getNames(nameTracker, item.getJSONArray("familyMembers"));
            }
            trackFirstName(nameTracker, item);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> nameTracker = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            String text = Files.toString(new File(JSON_DATA_FILE_PATH), Charsets.UTF_8);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(text);
            getNames(nameTracker, json.getJSONArray("members"));
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong.");
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : nameTracker.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper defined in jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar

Define a java class with fields similar to json pattern and then just bind them like:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;   

 ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
 objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
 objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);
 Family family=objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Family.class);
```

Now you will have a java object similar to your json string pattern and you can print it the way you like.